# Integrate on a logarithmic grid

Tags: numerical-integration

I am trying to solve numerically an integral equation, and from a couple of tests I can see that the result has a strong logarithmic divergence. For my specific problem it is very important to have accurate results in the region of very small arguments, but that doesn't work since I am forced to replace the lower limit of integration (zero, that is) with non-zero values (0.0001 or whatever) otherwise the program crashes.

So I though about integrating on a logarithmic grid, but I don't know how that works in Mathematica. (I have searched in the mathematica references, but could not find an answer). Anyone has an idea?

```
α = 2.85;
g = (Pi/2) α;
Nf := 2;

cs[x_] := 2 ArcCos[x]/Sqrt[1 - x^2];
csh[x_] := 2 ArcCosh[x]/Sqrt[x^2 - 1];
prefB[p_, k_, d_] :=
 (p^2 + k^2 (1 - 1/d^2))/Sqrt[p^2 d^4 - 1/4 ((p^2 + k^2) d^2/k - k )^2];
pieceB[k_, d_] := 
  If[d B[k]/k^2 < 1, cs[d B[k]/k^2], If[d B[k]/k^2 > 1, csh[d B[k]/k^2], 2]];

B[p_] = p^2 ;
iterstep := 
(values = 
Parallelize[
Table[{p, p^2 +  g/(Pi^3  Nf) (NIntegrate[ 
       prefB[p, k, d] ((d^2 B[k]^2/k^4 - 1) (Pi - g pieceB[k, d]) + 
           B[k ]/k^2 d  g^2 csh[g])/(d^2 B[k]^2/k^4 + g^2 - 1), 
       {d, 0, 1/(1 + p)}, {k, p d/(d + 1), p d/(1 - d)}, 
       WorkingPrecision -> 16, 
       PrecisionGoal -> 2, 
       MaxRecursion -> 100,
       AccuracyGoal -> 16, 
       Method -> {"SymbolicPreprocessing", "OscillatorySelection" -> False}] + 
      NIntegrate[
       prefB[p, k, d] ((d^2 B[k]^2/k^4 - 1) (Pi - g pieceB[k, d]) + 
           B[k ]/k^2 d  g^2 csh[g])/(d^2 B[k]^2/k^4 + g^2 -1), 
       {d, 1/(1 - p), Infinity}, 
       {k, p d/(d + 1), p d/(d - 1)}, 
        WorkingPrecision -> 16, PrecisionGoal -> 2, 
       MaxRecursion -> 100, AccuracyGoal -> 16,
       Method -> {"SymbolicPreprocessing","OscillatorySelection" -> False}])}, 
       {p, 0, 0.99999, 1/20}]];
     B[p_] = Interpolation[values , p, InterpolationOrder -> 4,   Method -> "Hermite"])

     Do[iterstep, {3}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

Comment: Can you include some code containing your specific problem?

Comment: If a certain input to `NIntegrate` causes *Mathematica* to crash, that should be reported to WRI as a bug. In any case I agree with @geordie: without a concrete example this question is going to be difficult to answer in a way that is likely to help you.

Comment: As said it is not just an integral, it is an integral equation. In fact I have uploaded the code the other day http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21303/testing-the-convergence-when-solving-an-integral-equation There I was asking a different question but since nobody answered (the user belisarius said he has an idea, but at the end he has probably forgotten) I have spent some time time thinking of alternative solution and got the idea of working on a logarithmic scale directly withing the integral (but I don't know how to implement this, I don't even know if it is possible...)

Comment: I have just edited the previous question to remove one of the two codes I have uploaded the first time. In the meantime I have managed to implement the convergence with a while loop (so I could solve the problem from the title, so to speak), but the problem of the integration limits remains :(

Comment: What Oleksandr and geordie are saying is "I don't understand your question". Try to give a small example of what you'd like to do (try not to hurl a page of code at us! just construct a minimal example).

Comment: @acl, thank you for your interest! Unfortunately it is difficult to construct a minimal example that reproduces exactly the troubling behavior (if I simplify the equations just a little, then it works), so I will try to explain once more in words: you might have noticed in the code that there is the external variable p, that should go from 0 to 1. Now if I integrate from 0.1 to 1, or from 0 to 0.9 then it works, and I can see that the solution explodes logarithmically when the argument is small.

Comment: I have tried in all sorts of ways to stabilize it (and failed) and this is really driving me mad since it is exactly the region of very small arguments that is important for my problem... Even if I chop the upper limit, I cannot be sure that there is no corresponding contribution that gets lost in the small momentum region as well. I hope the problem is clear and I really hope that someone here can help me...

Comment: you say "So I though about integrating on a logarithmic grid, but I don't know how that works in Mathematica". If you give an example of what you actually mean by this, perhaps someone can show you how to do it.

Comment: very roughly speaking what I have in mind is something analogous to the loglinear plot, where one can zoom into the logarithm when the argument takes very small values. Is it possible to change the scale 'while integrating', so that the result comes out directly on the logarithmic scale?

Comment: this is one possible solution I have thought of, but perhaps there is a better way to handle  the problem?

Comment: sorry, I literally do not understand what you are asking (mathematically). maybe someone else will.

Comment: @acl, forget the logarithmic scale... do you have a little time to have a look at the code from the link? you will easily notice that it breaks down if you replace {p,0,0.999} with {p,0,1}. Do you think there is any way to make it work? thank you so much!!!

Comment: @acl I think he is talking about numerical integration, and he means that if we used a naive integration method with uniform sampling (like a trapezoidal rule), then he is hoping for better results if the sampling is uniform on a logarithmic scale (i.e. the function is evaluated at points `Exp@Range[a,b,step]`).  Is this correct Micha?  If it is correct, why don't you just do a variable transformation in the integral?

Comment: I am not too experienced in numerical integration, but if you want to go into this in detail, all the documentaion you need is here: http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationStrategies.html  You can go as far as write your own integration method, or simply customize the available methods or piece a new method together from the available building blocks.

Comment: What would be particularly helpful is if you included a self-contained function to experiment with, and illustrate the problem with it in your question.  If it's really not possible to simplify the function more, then don't (though it should normally be possible to at least illustrate the problem with a simple example).  But make sure that you post a completely self contained function `f[x]` that people can experiment with, and decouple the integration question from the implementation details of that function.

Comment: @Szabolcs I have just posted the code, as I said I have explained my problem in a previous post (the link got lost here in the comments). I am supposed to find a solution for the function B[p], where p goes from zero to 1, but the problem is that as soon  as I approach either one of this limits, mathematica starts spiting errors (so that i have to integrate from 0 to 0.9). what I could see so far is that the solution is logarithmically divergent, which is probably the reason why mathematica cannot handle it. Is there any way one can go around the problem?

Comment: btw I have also tried to change the variable in the integral but then everything blows, probably it generates singularities someplace else... I am not very skilled with mathematica and I have worked quite hard to bring it this far, and it is really frustrating that nobody here can help me :(

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but the lower limit for `d` in the second integration is `1/(1-p)` which will evaluate to `ComplexInfinity` for `p=1`. Presumably the value of the second integration is zero for `p=1` so why not just wrap it in `If[p==1, 0, NIntegrate[...]]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the others I'm not 100% sure of what the problem is. When I run your code it looks fine. I slightly modified it:

```
values = ParallelTable[
    {p, p^2 + g/(Pi^3 Nf) (NIntegrate[prefB[p, k, d] ((d^2 B[k]^2/k^4 - 1) (Pi - g pieceB[k, d]) + 
        B[k]/k^2 d g^2 csh[g])/(d^2 B[k]^2/k^4 + g^2 - 1),
      {d, 0, 1/(1 + p)}, {k, p d/(d + 1), p d/(1 - d)}] +
    NIntegrate[prefB[p, k, d] ((d^2 B[k]^2/k^4 - 1) (Pi - g pieceB[k, d]) + 
        B[k]/k^2 d g^2 csh[g])/(d^2 B[k]^2/k^4 + g^2 - 1),
     {d, 1/(1 - p), Infinity}, {k, p d/(d + 1), p d/(d - 1)}])}, 
   {p,0,.98,.02}];
```

I get lots of warnings about non-convergence and complex values. I assume that the result is supposed to be real, because the imaginary part is very small. I'm not worried about that too much, since if I chop of the imaginary part and plot the function, it looks pretty regular:

```
f = Interpolation[Re@values];
Plot[f[x],{x,0,1}]
```

[image: Plot of the interpolated function]

Now I understand you are interested in the value at `p=1`, which is where Mathematica has trouble if you simply extend the range of `p` to 1. But you can get close by replacing `{p,0,.98,.02}` by this

```
{p, Range[0, .98, .02]~Join~(1 - 10^-Range[2, 8, .5])}
```

The plot looks pretty much the same, and by examining the table you can see that it seems to converge to 0.979533.

```
f[1]
(* => 0.979533 *)
Re@values[[-3;;]]
(* => {{1., 0.979532}, {1., 0.979533}, {1., 0.979533}} *)
```

Comment: Volker,thank you very much! It is true, I went around in circles a couple of times but the idea is to make the damn thing work, in a way or another. I didn't know about Join, now I am just running the code (it doesn't give errors yet but I suppose it will produce something). Now, if I may ask you another stupid question, how can I tell the iteration to stop when the convergence is achieved, for example when the absolute value between two consecutive solutions is less then say 10^-3? Again, thank you very much, you are pretty much saving my life :)

Comment: In that case I'd probably use a while loop instead of a table... but then it wouldn't work in parallel.